# Is it possible to pull data into java from a database dynamically?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have a project where I want to pull data from a database into a java project and then load that data to another database.
This can be easily done with spring batch when specifying the columns and table names. Is there a way to dynamically take in the table name and columns. For example I am thinking of creating a yaml with table info like below:

```
table_name:
    id: Long
    name: String
```

Any ideas how I can then pull id and name from table_name without making java classes with id and name? So it can be dynamically used.

Comment: You can execute any kind of sql in SpringJDBC  that you like. Including creating/modifying tables. I understand you want **even** more comfortable option of just doing it on orm level but that is unrealistic and even if you find a way to make it work going to end up being more cumbersome than jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

It may vary **A LOT** from database to database, but using a MySQL db as an example, you could:

- select all tables from a specific database:

  ```
  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName'
  ```

(run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName'` for more information)

- select all column names from a specific table:

  ```
  SELECT column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tableName' and table_schema = 'dbName'
  ```

(run `SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tableName' and table_schema = 'dbName'` for more information)

You can find a lot more metadata information from a (MySQL) database using the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html)